# Scientific Nomenclature: italics or roman in an italic environment

Tags: terminology, typography, science, emphasis, italics

[Scientific Nomenclature](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/page/scientific-nomenclature) says that:

> Italics are used for bacterial and viral taxa at the level of family
>   and below. All bacterial and many viral genes are italicized. Serovars
>   of *Salmonella enterica* are not italicized

When a sentence with a viral name is in an italicized environment (in a quote, in a reference list), should it be written in italics or roman? In `latex`, the `\emph` command provides such a relative "emphasis", with respect to the surrounding sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general advice is to revert to roman within a block of italics. Here are a couple of sources:

> - When a title or sentence is italicized, a word that normally would be italicized in running text—such as a foreign word, the scientific name of a plant or animal, or a ship—should appear in roman type. This is called reverse italics.
>   [- from the Editorial Style Guide, Purchase College, State University of New York](http://www.purchase.edu/departments/ccs/EditorialStyleGuide/GenStylePrefs/itals-underline.aspx)
> - 8.184 Terms within titles. A term in a quoted title that is itself normally italicized, such as a foreign word, a genus name, or the name of a ship, is set in roman type (“reverse italics”).
>   [- karencopyedits, quoting *The Chicago Manual of Style*](https://karencopyedits.wordpress.com/tag/style-guides/)

Comment: That was my natural idea. But I have hard times convincing my biologist colleagues

Comment: @LaurentDuval Perhaps the references to style guides would help. If you have style guides your colleagues consider authoritative, check there as well. If it's cast as aesthetics, though, all bets are off since *beauty is in the eye of the beholder* :) . Note the reason for italics, though - it's not really effective as 'heavy' emphasis (same font weight); it simply distinguishes one set of text from its surroundings. Toggling between italics and roman achieves that purpose. To make something stand out, use bold, underline, outline fonts, etc instead.